# can the definite integral be considered as the output of the indefinite integral function, or is there a way to obtain this?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, soft-question, indefinite-integrals

How to define the link between indefinite integral and definite integral?

Indefinite integral is a function, while definite integral is a number.

What is this number relatively to this function?

Could one say that, for every definite integral of *f(x)dx* from *a* to *b* , there is an indefinite integral of *f(t)dt* from *a* to *x*, lets call it function A, such that :

(1) *b* belongs to the domain of *A*

(2) the definite integral is the image of *b* under *A* ?

I tried to give an example of what I intend to say with the image above.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is an integrable function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$, then define$$\begin{array}{rccc}F\colon&[a,b]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt.\end{array}$$Then $F$ is an indefinite integral (or a primitive) of the function $f$ and$$\int_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm dt=F(b).$$